# iphone application ad-hoc installation on windows gives invalid certificate error

Tags: windows-vista, iphone, certificate

I've an application that need to be deployed to some testers. those with windows machine are reporting that the certificate used for signing the application couldn't be installed because of an unknown critical extension (1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4)

is there a way to make that critical extension known to windows (vista 64bit specifically)?

I'm guessing that all this system of extension give user the ability to register callbacks to interpret the various added extensions (it would be totally useless otherwise)

Comment: Let me get this straight: you have an iPhone app that communicates with a Windows computer, but needs some certificate? Or you want to install it from a Windows computer on your iPhone but the computer doesn't let you?

Comment: the second one: I've an iphone app, signed via an Apple issued developer certificate, distributed via an ad hoc distribution profile. That combination of stuff works under mac and windows xp, but doesn't under vista, because the certificate is rejected by vista.